# InvalidCastException for COM object in Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, windows, iis, com

I have a problem with a site which communicates to a C# service deployed on IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 (x64 version).
The service is trying to access a COM object from a third party dll. When is doing that an exception of the following form is thrown:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'MyClass' to interface type 'TheirInterface'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{88B11E8A-0B27-459C-BC28-A4D4113FD4AE}' failed due 
to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

I hosted the same site on many other machines working on Windows 7, so I suppose that the problem is related to the OS (Windows Server 2008).
Any suggestion about wher I can search a solution for this exception, or if there is any configurations that should be made on the IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either run the website as a 32-bit website or use a COM object compiled against the x64 platform. In other words your COM object was unable to be load because it only supports being loaded by a 32-bit process.